# Printing final sum of integers in a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I am learning Java and am having a very simple problem.

How to print the final sum from a while loop?

if I enter integers 10 10 40
the output I get is
10
20
60
but am only trying to get the final 60.

This answer can also relate to printing the final anything in a while loop as I just can't seem to get this.

my sample code below...

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a sequence of numbers to sum up: ");
    double total = 0;
    while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
        double input = in.nextDouble();
        total = total + input;

     System.out.println("The Sum is: " + total);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your output line is  not within the loop. I hence flatly doubt that you get output as described. Please make sure to provide a [mre] which demonstrates the described behaviour.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue.  The output you've described is impossible for the code you've written.  Run the code again and update the question.

Comment: I have edited the code. The print statement was not in the scope of the loop and was giving  blank output in the console. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you have put the print statement inside the loop.

Also, `in.hasNextDouble()` doesn't make sense for input from the keyboard; it is useful when you are reading data from a file or a `Scanner` for some string. You can use an infinite loop (e.g. `while(true){...}`) and break it when there is no input from the user.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sequence of numbers to sum up, press Enter without any input to exit: ");
        double total = 0;
        while (true) {
            String input = in.nextLine();
            if (input.isBlank()) {
                break;
            }
            total += Double.parseDouble(input);
        }
        System.out.println("The Sum is: " + total);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a sequence of numbers to sum up, press Enter without any input to exit: 
10
20
30

The Sum is: 60.0
```

**A demo of a `Scanner` for a string:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner("10 20 30");
        double total = 0;
        while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
            double input = in.nextDouble();
            total = total + input;
        }
        System.out.println("The Sum is: " + total);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The Sum is: 60.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in: `System.out.println("The Sum is: " + total);`

If you would like for only the final sum to be printed it needs to be outside of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Please, print the total outside of the loop and it will work fine !
Code:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sequence of numbers to sum up: ");
        double total = 0;
        while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
            double input = in.nextDouble();
            total = total + input;
        }
        System.out.println("The Sum is: " + total);
    }
```